# React JS + Material UI : displaying N elements inside a container of variable width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What I'm trying to do should be something extremly simple but still I cannot seem to get it done right with Material UI (ReactJS):

I have a Card element that shows some image, a title, a description and some buttons. This element has a FIXED width and height.
I want to display N amount of this elements, one after each other, inside a container element who's WIDTH may vary.

So, if the container element's width is 1000px and the Card elements are 250px, it will dispaly 4 Card elements in a row. And if I then set a width of 500px for the container,  it should display 2 Card elements in a row and the other 2 below in a new row.

About a decade ago when I was still doing html+css I used to do this using a DIV with a specific width and some other floated DIVs inside -also with fixed width- and it would render in this way I explained... I mean, the "overflow" from a row would automatcally go to the row below.

I have tried many different things, I also searched for photo album tutorials and things like that and still can't get it done...

How am I supposed to do this kind of things with Material UI and ReactJS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with these kinds of problems using flex-box. Here I did a simple example just using a couple of properties that should fit our description: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cdn-cbb6mx?file=/src/App.js

In this link, you can find a very nice guide about flex-box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/